# How to find and click search result?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need driver to find a specific element in search result and click on it.
Simple ways like search by linktext, xpath, css etc and click at it don't work. I've tried to wait 120 second for the results to load but it did not help clicking it.

here's my html with the search results:

```
<div class="searchSection active" data-form="formAddUser">
<p>
<div class="searchResult">
<div class="user ctrlClickSubmit clear" data-photo="img/avatar-anonymous-big.png" data-user="Stephanie" data-form="formSelectObserver" data-value="2046_backgroundOff">
<div class="user ctrlClickSubmit clear" data-photo="f/user-photo/c/2/828.jpg?1429176076" data-user="Caroline" data-form="formSelectObserver" data-value="828_backgroundOff">
<p class="avatar fl">
<img alt="" src="f/user-photo/c/2/828.jpg?1429176076"/>
</p>
<p class="bold ctrlSearchList">Caroline</p>
<p>My Company name</p>
</div>
```

The result I'm trying to click at is "Caroline".

And here are ways I tried doing it:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='new-users-research-content']/div[2]/div/div/p/button")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("search-profile")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.name("search-profile")).sendKeys(""+UserName);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,120);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("[@data-user='" + UserName +"']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='formSelectObserver']/div/div[1]//p[contains(text(),'" + UserName +"')]"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.bold.ctrlSearchList")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[text()='" + UserName + "']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.addObserver > p.btnSection > button.btn.ctrlClickSubmit")).click();
```

Any ideas??

Comment: `By.cssSelector("[data-user='Caroline']")` should work, have you tried ?

Comment: @EugenHalca yes, I've tried that and it did not work

Comment: what error messages do you get?

Comment: "element not found in cache"

Comment: @EugenHalca your answer isn't fully correct. here's what worked for me: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-user='Caroline']")).click(); and I surely got that thanks to you!! thank you :)